# Can I revert a transformation in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

Let's say I have transformed an layer/element in Photoshop and I'm well past the point of being able to undo, or it would be highly inconvenient. Is there a way to revert the transformation back to 100% size, 0° rotation, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the transformations are no longer in the History Panel, then there is no way to revert them.

The exception would be smart objects. If you transform a smart object, you can always revert the smart object to the default state.

Comment: This is helpful, although discouraging if true. I'll hold out for a little to see if someone else has a solution, but if not I'll accept this.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the way it is. Transformations obey the same rules every other tool in Photoshop does when it comes to history -- once it's gone it's gone. The only suggestion I could make is you keep track of what you transformed manually, or you make an action for it (and an action to undo it).